# Laravel load only Model

Tags: laravel, model, eloquent

I want to load only the model to be able to add wheres etc later.

```
$query = Users;

if($request->filter == 1) {
   $query = $query->where('user_access', 'admin');
}

if($request->otherFilter == 1) {
   $query = $query->where('user_email', '');
)

$query->get();
```

Although using $query = Users; doesn't work..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it by creating a `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder` instance as:

```
$query = Users::query();
```

and then you can add further queries in query builder instance.

Answer (score 1):

You can just create an instanse of the `Users` model with:

```
$query = new Users;
```

And then work with it.

Answer (score 0):

You should really consider using local query scopes with Eloquent if you are planning to do lots of different queries.
[Laravel Eloquent Query Scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#query-scopes)

```
    //App\User.php

    public function scopePopular($query)
    {
        return $query->where('votes', '>', 100);
    }

    $users = App\User::popular()->orderBy('created_at')->get();
```

You can create custom queries instead of long verbose ones.

Comment: The question is about how to chain more queries by the filters not about to how clean the code.